# What is this dot? Not fireflies question

Tags: objects, 3d-view, interface

I fat fingered a key, saw it show up; how do I get rid of it?  What is it? It shows like the orange dot that marks the last selected object,  but it's white; orange dot is still doing it's thing on other objects. ty.

[image: Dot thats going to make me off myself]

Comment: it doesn't become orange when you select it?

Comment: Yeah it does   (Comments have to be 15 characters to post (filler to achieve that lol))  EDIT: No it doesn't lol

Answer (score 2):

It may be the origin of an object that has no more vertices in it, for example maybe you deleted all the vertices of an object in *Edit* mode, but didn't delete the object itself in *Object* mode, so the object itself still exists even if it has no more vertices, and its origin is still displayed. So select it and press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete.

Answer (score 1):

Isolate it - I think it's a vertex or origin of a bounding box sort of. You have a lot of available layers. Move it and check the outliner to see what's active. Then, look at properties and check the dimensions against the size of the bounding box. You could make the Bounding Box visible in the Data Tab (I think) or Object Tab by controlling the maximum draw. See the box and object take the same size.

In Edit Mode, clean up by deleting loose geometry or vertices to see if that does it (assuming the Bounding Box idea isn't yielding any happy). Report back!

EDIT or Ensure the origin is with the geometry. [T] option. The Properties will report Location based on an object's origin; if there's a big disparity between what you see and what's listed, that's probably it. Another tip-off is you select an object most of the time by its origin.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,  I was able to select it by clicking on it (who knew lol). Wasn't anything visible in my scene though.  Outliner says it was a cylinder.  I couldn't scale it small enough or large enough to actually see it though.  *Shrugs*  it's gone though; deleted it.  Don't know... :) Thanks though.