# Unknown Orange Dot

Tags: interface

I'm sure this is just a simple fix, but I can't figure out how to remove it. There's an orange dot that appeared in the 3D viewport that follows my view movement, and at times it has turned into a cross. What is this and how can I get rid of it? I feel like I must've toggled something on by mistake...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that that's the origin of some object?  Can you add a screenshot of your outliner window with everything in it expanded?

Comment: I sometimes get random useless origins, so that might be what this is. If it is, just group select the area of the dot and hit delete or shift-x. I'm not putting this as an answer because I do not know whether it is the same thing or not. Please tell me if I am right or wrong. 

Comment: Outliner screenshot added! I tried deleting everything and it's still there! I'm wondering if it's a mode that I accidentally keyed into.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129954/what-is-this-dot-not-fireflies-question

Comment: It definitely could be an object with no vertices, but I've tried deleting everything in the outliner and it still is visible. I've added a gif to the main post to show that the dot follows my field of view.

Comment: Update: I think it has something to do with curves/nurbs, but I still don't know how to get rid of it.

Comment: Are you using any add-on ?

Comment: In case that you cant find the solution yet, here I found a video, because I had the same problem. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl1VTB_btY0

Comment: CTRL + ALT + B worked for me, in case anybody stumbles upon this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Its the render region marker, it is always on a fixed position on the screen not in the world. you can remove it by clicking on view tab and unchecking render region just under local cam

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in Blender 3.4.1.0. Tick *Origins* under *Overlays*
[image]